# Installing Lexmark X1290 printer?

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, printing

I'm trying to install the Lexmark X1290 printer on a 64-bit Ubuntu 10.10 system. I previously had this printer working flawlessly on a 32-bit Ubuntu 10.04.

I'm following the instructions from [http://www.trodrigues.net/wiki/linux:ubuntu:lexmark_x1290](http://web.archive.org/web/20080119224658/http://www.trodrigues.net/wiki/linux%3aubuntu%3alexmark_x1290) and using the  Z600 series driver from Lexmark.

**Create a directory named lexmark and unpack the driver:**

```
mkdir lexmark
tar -xvzf CJLZ600LE-CUPS-1.0-1.TAR.gz
```

**Extract the driver from the install script:**

```
tail -n +143 z600cups-1.0-1.gz.sh > install.tar.gz
```

**And untar it:**

```
tar -xvzf install.tar.gz
```

This generates 2 drivers (`z600cups-1.0-1.i386.rpm` and `z600llpddk-2.0-1.i386.rpm`) that then should be converted to `.deb` files with `alien` and installed with `dpkg`, but -as the filenames already indicate- the drivers are for 32-bit systems and not for 64-bit systems. Hence the error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb 
dpkg: error processing z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb (--install):
  package architecture (i386) does not match system (amd64)
  Errors were encountered while processing: z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb
```

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this driver, but you could force the installation by running:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i z600cups_1.0-2_i386.deb
```

It might still not work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: This did indeed the trick! (a note to people in the same position and following the above mentioned tutorial: if you get a CUPS 'server-error-internal-error' after selecting the .ppd.gz, just gunzip and select the .ppd file.)

Comment: PS: Oli, if you have an account on superuser and provide the same answer to the the question there: http://superuser.com/questions/216738/installing-lexmark-x1290-printer-on-64-bit-ubuntu-10-10 I'll accept it as the correct answer there as well.

Comment: Glad it worked and I've Answered that one too :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is additional information needed as of 2018 (that is, to install Lexmark X1290 printer on Ubuntu 18.04):

1. The procedure fails at `alien` invocation on a 64-bit system:

   > z600cups-1.0-1.i386.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot
   >   be built on this system

   I could "fool" it by converting to `.tgz` format first, then to `.deb`:

   ```
   sudo alien -t z600cups-1.0-1.i386.rpm
   sudo alien -t z600llpddk-2.0-1.i386.rpm
   sudo alien z600cups-1.0.tgz
   sudo alien z600llpddk-2.0.tgz
   ```

   After which the installation worked:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i z600cups_1.0-2_all.deb 
   sudo dpkg -i z600llpddk_2.0-2_all.deb
   ```
2. The `z600` backend and `rastertoz600` filter need the 32-bit versions of specific libs. I had to install `libstdc++5:i386`, `libcups2:i386` and `libcupsimage2:i386`.
3. After restarting CUPS, I did not have to manually select the PPD file. Model Z600 showed up in the list of Lexmark models.

(Steps taken on Linux Mint 19, based on Ubuntu 18.04)