# How to use driver for printer?

Tags: drivers, printing

I've been trying to get my Lexmark x1290 to work on Ubuntu 12.04.

According to this [**post**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15537/installing-lexmark-x1290-printer), the z600 driver should work to print, so I downloaded the z600 driver from [**here**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters/LexmarkPrinters?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=lexmark.z600-0.4.deb) and installed it through the Ubuntu Software Center.

I plugged in my printer and went to the "Printer" section under **System Settings...** and followed the wizard to install it.  It showed up as "1200-series" but never gave me a choice to choose the driver and when I try to print to it, it pops up a message that it is printing and then that it is done printing, but it is definitely not printing anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this work for you? [How to Install a Lexmark z600 series printer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50144/how-to-install-a-lexmark-z600-series-printer)

Comment: Nope. I did these steps and it still is not working: 
    install libstdc++5 from synaptic.
    install getlibs-all.deb.
    install lexmark.z600-0.4.deb.
    go to System/Administration/Printing.
    choose Lexmark z600 printer

Comment: It worked fine for me. I used the Ubuntu Software Center to install the driver and then I went to Printers and added it. The new driver appeared at the end of the drivers list for Lexmark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your printer but you can search for it by using

```
ls /bin/ /usr/bin/ | sort | grep "your printer name"
```

and then you can configure it